# Series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

If $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of orthogonal functions in a Hilbert space $H$, such that $\sum_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{H}^{2}<\infty$. Does this imply that the series $\sum_{n}f_{n}$ belongs to the space $H$?

Comment: Yes: check that the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy, and use completeness.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Thanks for your comment. Does the orthogonality has anything to do with this?

Comment: Yes, otherwise take $f_n:=f/n$, where $f\neq 0$ is an element of $H$.

Comment: To expand on @DavideGiraudo's comment, orthogonality gives you $\|\sum f_n\| = \sqrt{\sum \|f_n\|^2}$, but $\sum \|f_n\|^2 < \infty$ does not imply $\sum \|f_n\| < \infty$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I was wondering how to make the square inside the summation sign, now I know why! Thanks all!

Comment: Yeah, getting the square inside the summation sign is called Pythagoras' Theorem and is works whenever the f_n are pairwise orthogonal

Answer (score 1):

Let $s_n:=\sum_{j=1}^nf_n$. We have, using orthogonality,
$$\left\lVert s_{m+n}-s_n\right\rVert^2=\left\lVert \sum_{j=n+1}^{m+n}f_j\right\rVert^2=\sum_{j=n+1}^{m+n}\left\lVert f_j\right\rVert^2\leqslant \sum_{j=n+1}^{+\infty}\left\lVert f_j\right\rVert^2.$$
As the series $\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\left\lVert f_j\right\rVert^2$ is convergent, the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is Cauchy in $H$. We conclude by completeness.

If $\{f_n\}$ is not assumed orthogonal, the result may fail. For example, if $f\in H$, $f\neq 0$, then $f_n:=\frac 1nf$ is such that 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\left\lVert f_j\right\rVert^2<\infty$$
holds, but the sequence $\{s_n\}=\{\sum_{j=1}^n\frac 1jf\}$ is not convergent in $H$, as it's not bounded.